# Design pattern to reduce code duplication

Tags: c#, design-patterns, code-duplication

Lets assume we have 2 sets of classes, one is contains Files (i.e File1, File2 ...), second called Blocks (Block1, Block2,...). Files can contain different amount of blocks properties:

```
class File1
{
    public Block1 Block1Prop {get;set;}
    public Block8 Block8Prop {get;set;}
}

class File2
{
    public Block1 Block1Prop {get;set;}
    public Block9 Block9Prop {get;set;}
}

class File1
{
    public Block9 Block9Prop {get;set;}
    public Block7 Block7Prop {get;set;}
    public Block4 Block4Prop {get;set;}
    public Block3 Block3Prop {get;set;}
}

class File1
{
    public Block8 Block8Prop {get;set;}
}

. . .
```

and blocks are just separate classes:

```
class Block1
{
    public string SomeProperty {get;set}
}

class Block2
{
    public string SomeProperty {get;set}
}

. . .
```

So to not write same block property (in FileX) over and over again, I've separated the blocks which occur in all files to base abstract class. For the remaining blocks, I can create an interface for each one, then implement it in files (but that wold not reduce code duplication).

```
interface IBlock1
{
    Block1 Block1Prop {get;set;}
}

interface IBlock8
{
    Block8 Block8Prop {get;set;}
}

class File1: IBlock1, IBlock8
{
    public Block1 Block1Prop {get;set;}
    public Block8 Block8Prop {get;set;}
}
```

So, is there any simple way (some known design pattern) to avoid code duplication or this type of hierarchy should be written in this way?

Comment: May I know why you are creating separate classes like `File1`, `File2` to `FileN` and so on and `Block1`, `Block2` to `BlockN` and so on? What if you have only one `File` class and one `Block` class and instantiate them multiple times? Just to clarify I am asking. Plus can you tell us in what sort of context you are trying to apply this?

Comment: From my understanding you have an object object that have N properties in a list of X possible properties. Is it possible for those object to herite those property from other class instead of implementing an interface.

Comment: I really think this this just a semantic issue that lead you there. You do not wan't to _implement_ the interface. You just want to inherit from it. The difference is Interface = rewrite the code to fullfil the contract. Inherance= You don't have to rewrite anything from the master class.

Comment: Well... context is, that some method will make request files from that Files.

Comment: The problem is that multiple inheritance is not allowed. This project would be some kind of parser (or serializer) that would create some files out of user input.